# Should a low-overhead file writing process be on it's own thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, logging, file-io

I have a wpf app writing to a text logfile fairly infrequently (from 0.25s to 4s between writes).
Each write is one short line of text.
I don't flush after every write.

At the moment, this is called directly on the main UI thread, as I figure the length of time taken isn't even beginning to become close to being a concern.

..Is the right way to do it, though?
Should I have the logging process on it's own thread, and send some asynchronous event to it to log the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at NLog, Spring or any of the multitude of logging platforms.  Make your app cool and worry about the best way to do logging later.  Logging calls will be made from your gui methods, how they are implemented should be abstracted onto a framework so you can put them on different threads etc. if required.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest trying [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)?  It handles all of this for you in a very simple, lightweight and easy to use package.

Comment: I agree that Log4Net is well worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

File writes are buffered by the file system cache.  It takes but a handful of microseconds.  You'd have to write at a rate of ~10 megabytes per second or have a heavily fragmented hard drive to ever get the cache to fill up so that you have to wait for the disk.  You're not close to this by a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

I think at this write rate, you would get more overhead from the thread(context switches, syncronize it, etc.) than not doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a big deal in your case to keep logging process in the UI thread, however I personally would prefer to write the logs in a different thread because doing so separate the work of logging from your main thread and that good for maintainability and it is commonly that logs may be more frequent due to requirement change or bug tracing or maybe you would like to change to windows event log..

I think going with a logging thread is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a lot at MSDN's [Managed Threading Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx), particularly the note about [Parallel Programming in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx). Plus I'd personally recommend you to rely on a logging framework such as [Apache log4net](http://logging.apache.org/).